# If you install Monero GUI over Tails, should you install the blockchain on same drive as Tails

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I plan to use Tails to install the Monero GUI on a Win 10 PC and then download the blockchain to run a full Monero node.I plan to always use Monero over Tails, The Tails OS will be stored on 32GB USB Flash drive.

My questions:

1. Can I install the full node (blockchain) on a section of my hardrive on my PC? I discovered that my PC has been partitioned already and I have 150 GB unused. I plan to install my full node here. Or should I install it on the same USB flash drive as the Tails is stored on?
2. Where would be a good place to store the GUI? Or doesn't it matter? If it is OK i can store the full node and GUI on the Hard Drive.

Answer (score 0):

> If you install Monero GUI over Tails, should you install the blockchain on same drive as Tails

You don't have to. This is up to you. If it's not on the same drive, wherever you do sync the blockchain to will need to be mounted in Tails when you want to use it.

> Can I install the full node (blockchain) on a section of my hardrive on my PC?

Yes.

> Or should I install it on the same USB flash drive as the Tails is stored on?

You state above that your flash drive is only 32 GB. Even with a pruned full node, you will struggle to fit both OS and full node on the same drive.

> Where would be a good place to store the GUI? Or doesn't it matter?

Wherever you like. It's your computer.

> If it is OK I can store the full node and GUI on the Hard Drive.

If you have space for them both, that's fine.